# Edit community answer

Tags: discussion

Please see this question [community answer](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/142/is-there-a-comprehensive-source-for-poker-terminology)

It has **Float** as

> Calling a bet on one street with the intention of winning the hand on
>   a future street without going to showdown.

To me a float is a hand I think is good but no desire to inflate the pot.  I do want to take it to showdown and hoping to avoid more bets.

I would like answers / comments before I edit.

And I would add **Flat** as slightly different as I am calling not sure it is good.  Hoping to improve and don't want to inflate the pot. If it does not improve I may bluff it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree. "Floating" is a bluff play.

http://www.thepokerbank.com/strategy/plays/float/

This is merely the first example from a basic search of "making a float play" but I believe it is accurate. I think the description we are currently using is OK but could be improved I suppose.

Comment: Then I will leave it alone